# PHP & MySQLi : Count number of queries within a PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli

How to count the number of queries within a PHP script?

or Do I need to save the counter into a global variable and +1 when a `mysqli_query` function is called?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To count how many queries in single PHP run, make a global counter and increment by one for every query call ( optionally successful query count too )